# webclient exception 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, ddos, webclient

Если открывать через браузер, то видна проверка от ddos-guard, может что то нужно добавить в запрос? Или как то дождаться ответ и перенаправление?

Пробовал через команду curl.

```
string text = string.Empty;

        string url = "";//курсы цб

        Uri urlAddress = new Uri(url);

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {                       
                text = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //пишем в логи
            }                
        }
```

Comment: 1. WebClient является устаревшим компонентом в C#. 2. `видна проверка от ddos-guard` - если вы видите это, то простыми заголовками или чем либо "простым" вы не обойдетесь, нужно разгадывать защиту, либо использовать полноценный браузер в проекте. Если у вас это "курс", то есть куча альтернатив.

Comment: Кроме того, у cbr.ru, если речь идет о нём, похоже, есть проверка на "гнилые IPшники" - видимо, у некотрых адресов постепенно накапливается "плохая карма", и с них запросы перестают работать - просто на запрос возвращается Forbidden